# knn.fit() error: valueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm doing supervised learning course on data camp. And trying to reproduce the code in jupiter notebook.

I do the following :

```
url = 'https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/628/datasets/444cdbf175d5fbf564b564bd36ac21740627a834/diabetes.csv'

df2 = pd.read_csv(url)


y = df2['diabetes'].values
X = df2.loc[:,['pregnancies', 'bmi','age']]
X = np.array(X)

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 42)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=6)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I do knn.fit() it gives me an error:
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [460, 308]

I look through some solutions here, basically it's all about X and y 
array dimensions, I changed them but it didn't help.

Thank you in advance!

```
print(X.shape, y.shape)
print(type(X), type(y))
```

(768, 3) (768,)
class 'numpy.ndarray'
class 'numpy.ndarray'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), `train_test_split` creates train-test subsets in the same order as arguments that are passed in it.

This will fix your problem:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 42)
```